# Trouble with DoCmd.OpenReport with a complicated Where Clause (Syntax Issue)

Tags: sql, ms-access, vba

So first I have gone over a very large amount of other sources trying to look for a solution or an explanation of my error, but I haven't found anything that helps me quite yet.

I have been learning all this stuff on my own so I am definitely lacking in some of the foundation knowledge and it has caught up to me. Basically the form I am having trouble with allows the user to generate three different reports based on the kind of criteria they care about. There are three different combo boxes cboCompany, cboProject, cboEmployee. I use the Nz command to change null values to zero and then use If Statements to  determine which report to use depending on what the user selects. I hope that kind of makes since. Its easier to show than explain. That part all works fine though.

The problem I'm getting is when I want to do a print preview for the report the user generates. I need the where clause to take the values the user selects to use in the print preview. I can't get the syntax right for the where clause to actually do this.

Here is how I call my variables. The Nz function as I understand require the variables to be variants, because of this I'm not quite sure how to write the syntax for the where clause. I know integers, strings, and dates all have different syntax but I don't know what variant would be.

```
Dim Company As Variant
Dim Project As Variant
Dim Employee As Variant
Dim EndDate As String
Dim StartDate As String

Company = Nz(cboCompany, 0)
Project = Nz(cboProject, 0)
Employee = Nz(cboEmployee, 0)
StartDate = txtStartDate.Value
EndDate = txtEndDate.Value
```

So this next part is how I have written one of the report options with my best guess of the syntax for the where clause. It doesn't work so If you could help point me in the right direction I would greatly appreciate it.

```
 ElseIf Company <> 0 And Project <> 0 And Employee <> 0 Then
    DoCmd.OpenReport "ProjectReport_Employee_R", acViewPreview, "", "[cboCompany]= " & Company & " And [cboEmployee]= " & Employee & " And [cboProject]= " & Project & " And [txtStartDate]= #" & StartDate & "# And [txtEndDate]= #" & EndDate & "#", acWindowNormal
```

If I don't explain things well enough or you need more code to help please let me know, and thank you in advance.

***Edit: Just to give a more complete picture this is the code behind the entire form.

```
Private Sub cboCompany_AfterUpdate()
    Me.cboProject.Requery
End Sub

Private Sub cmdSubmit_Click()
    
    'Open Report With Filter Criteria
    Dim Company As Variant
    Dim Project As Variant
    Dim Employee As Variant
    
    Company = Nz(cboCompany, 0)
    Project = Nz(cboProject, 0)
    Employee = Nz(cboEmployee, 0)
    
    If Company = 0 Then
        MsgBox ("Please Select At Least A Company To Generate A Report")
        cboCompany.Value = Null
        cboProject.Value = Null
        cboEmployee.Value = Null
        
    ElseIf Company <> 0 And Project = 0 And Employee = 0 Then
        DoCmd.BrowseTo acBrowseToReport, "ProjectReport_Company_R", "Main_F.NavigationSubform>ProjectReport_F.Child31"
    
    ElseIf Company <> 0 And Project <> 0 And Employee = 0 Then
        DoCmd.BrowseTo acBrowseToReport, "ProjectReport_Project_R", "Main_F.NavigationSubform>ProjectReport_F.Child31"
    
    ElseIf Company <> 0 And Project <> 0 And Employee <> 0 Then
        DoCmd.BrowseTo acBrowseToReport, "ProjectReport_Employee_R", "Main_F.NavigationSubform>ProjectReport_F.Child31"
    
    ElseIf Company <> 0 And Project = 0 And Employee <> 0 Then
        MsgBox ("Please Select A Project")
        
    End If
    
End Sub

Private Sub Form_Current()
 Me.cboCompany.SetFocus
End Sub

Private Sub Form_Load()
   
'Set Date Values
   Dim EndDate As String
   Dim StartDate As String
        StartDate = Format(DateSerial(Year(Date), Month(DateAdd("m", -1, Date)), 16), "Short Date")
        EndDate = Format(DateSerial(Year(Date), Month(Date), 15), "Short Date")
    
    txtStartDate.Value = StartDate
    txtEndDate.Value = EndDate

'Set The Form Message on Open Child31
    DoCmd.BrowseTo acBrowseToForm, "ProjectReport_Message_F", "Main_F.NavigationSubform>ProjectReport_F.Child31"
    
   
    
End Sub
'------------------------------------------------------------
' Print_Click
'
'------------------------------------------------------------
Private Sub Command39_Click()
On Error GoTo Command39_Click_Err

    Dim Company As Variant
    Dim Project As Variant
    Dim Employee As Variant
    Dim EndDate As String
    Dim StartDate As String
    
    Company = Nz(cboCompany, 0)
    Project = Nz(cboProject, 0)
    Employee = Nz(cboEmployee, 0)
    StartDate = txtStartDate.Value
    EndDate = txtEndDate.Value
    
    
    If Company <> 0 And Project = 0 And Employee = 0 Then
    
        DoCmd.OpenReport "ProjectReport_Company_R", acViewPreview, "", "", acNormal
        
    ElseIf Company <> 0 And Project <> 0 And Employee = 0 Then
    
        DoCmd.OpenReport "ProjectReport_Project_R", acViewPreview, "", "", acNormal
        
    ElseIf Company <> 0 And Project <> 0 And Employee <> 0 Then
    
        DoCmd.OpenReport "ProjectReport_Employee_R", acViewPreview, "", "[cboCompany]= " & Company & " And [cboEmployee]= " & Employee & " And [cboProject]= " & Project & " And [txtStartDate]= '" & StartDate & "' And [txtEndDate]= '" & EndDate & "'", acWindowNormal
    
    End If


Command39_Click_Exit:
    Exit Sub

Command39_Click_Err:
    MsgBox Error$
    Resume Command39_Click_Exit

End Sub
```

Comment: What are your Variant fields in the database? That will define how you should handle them.

Comment: When I say it doesn't work, it doesn't get an error but the parameters are not entered. So for instance the user will enter a company, a project and an employee and the report will generate just fine on the subreport, but when I hit the print button that is tied to the DoCmd.OpenReport done of that information is transferred so I am trying to include it in the where clause but as of yet I can't get the syntax correct

Comment: also company, project, and employee will all be integers. Startdate and Enddate are of course date fields. If that helps. Again I'm not sure how access works behind scenes so I don't know if I define them as integers or something else

Comment: I think I should explain better exactly how I have this set up. And please excuse my ignorance I'm sure this is not a "good practice" way of doing things but giving my limited knowledge this is how I've made it work. The subreport that the user generates is based off a query where I set parameters for EmployeeID, ProjectID, and CompanyID equal to cboEmployee, cboProject, and cboCompany. This allows the report to generate in the subreport no problem but the parameter values are not transfering to the print preview of the report. Thats why I want to include them in the where clause for OpenRepor

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you may be using the wrong field names in the filter.

Suppose that in Report Design your report's RecordSource is tblProject.

When you do this:

```
  DoCmd.OpenReport "ProjectReport_Employee_R", , , "[cboCompany]= " & Company ...
```

you are effectively opening the report with a recordsource of:

```
  SELECT * FROM tblProject WHERE [cboCompany] = 12345 AND ...
```

If tblProject doesn't have a field named "cboCompany" then it won't work.

Comment: True, but all the reports are based on queries in the queries I set the where clause to equal cboCompany. This works great for populating the report in the subreport, but not so much for the print preview. It keeps asking me for the parameters cboCompany, etc. I'm trying to fill it in with the where clause which I think should work, but I'm not confident of my syntax. I'm also pretty sure this is a poor way to code lol. But I had to make due with the knowledge I had. I rather not rework the whole system, just get this function to work then I can be done

Comment: I also want to say thank you for bothering to help me. I really appreciate you using your free time for a stranger

Comment: I don't understand "populating the report in the subreport".  Do you mean populating a subform on the main form, with a form-oriented view of the data that will eventually be on the report?

Comment: I can't figure out how to post just a .png file to show you a screen shot so you get a better idea of what is happening. There are basically 3 combo boxes and 2 date boxes which the user selects from and then hits submit and that calls up a report in the sub report box. A little child window on the form. The report is queried with values for CompanyID to equal cboCompany... one of the choices. That all works fine and the reports are generated my problem is printing. I want to print the same report with the user chosen fields, but my where clause is not appeasing the parameters it is asking for

Comment: You can't post an image in a comment. You need to edit your original question, and add the image at the end along with something saying it was added as an edit.  Your problem is that you are trying to compare [cboCompany] to 12345, when in fact they are equal. You want to compare ***CompanyID*** to 12345. Rewrite your filter like this:  `"CompanyID=" & Company & " And EmployeeID=" & Employee & " And ...`

Comment: This worked Tom thanks. I got confused because the parameters were asking for the value of cboCompany so that was what I needed worry about. Now that its fixed that seems incredibly obvious. Thanks for  taking the time to teach me

Comment: RecordSources are strange. Whenever Access compiles the SQL for a RecordSource, anything that cannot be understood at compile time is considered to be a parameter. This includes any reference to form controls. At run time, Access needs to fill in values for the parameters. The "[cboCompany]" parameter can obtain its value from the form field of the same name, but only if the RecordSource is being used ***from within the form***.  A subform is inside the form. A report is not inside the form, even though DoCmd.OpenReport is.    ...continued

Comment: If you have a particular report that will always be run from a particular form, it is common to omit the filter in the OpenReport. Instead, the report's RecordSource can pluck the required parameters directly from the form by using ***fully-qualified names***. Set the report's RecordSource to `SELECT * FROM tblProject WHERE CustomerID = [Forms]![Project Report Selection]![cboCustomer]`.  You can now run the report from anywhere (not just a DoCmd from within the form) and the report will work, so long as the [Project Report Selection] form is open.

Comment: Thank You!! I had no idea something like that would work. That helps immensely. Should have been doing that from the get go

Answer (score 0):

I would base the report on a query rather than using the DoCmd's "WhereCondition" argument.

Make the "ProjectReport_Employee_R" recordsource a query called "qryProjectReport_Employee_R".

...then modify the query definition every time you want to run the report.

For example:

sub print_report()

'add these
   dim qdf as Dao.Querydef
   dim strSQL as String

if this then

ElseIf Company <> 0 And Project <> 0 And Employee <> 0 Then

```
'SQL may need modifying...
strSQL= "SELECT * FROM SomeTable WHERE [cboCompany]= " & Company & " And [cboEmployee]= " & Employee & " And [cboProject]= " & Project & " And [txtStartDate]= #" & StartDate & "# And [txtEndDate]= #" & EndDate & "#"

Set qdf="qryProjectReport_Employee_R"
qdf.SQL=strSQL

DoCmd.OpenReport "ProjectReport_Employee_R", acViewPreview

'clean up
set qdf=nothing
```

end if 
end sub

That's all.  Let me know if you have any questions.

Comment: Oh ok I see what you are suggesting. I'll give it a try and let you know

Comment: I copied what you had with of course changing the names, but I get a compile error. It highlights the qdf.SQL=strSQL line. Can you explain what the qdf part is suppose to do and then I can maybe make better sense of it. pardon my ignorance of course. I'm sure this is very basic